# Surfaces that reflect UV rays

Tags: visible-light, radiation, reflection

I've been trying to research what surfaces reflect UV rays for the past day but it's been difficult coming up with definitive answers.

So far what I've found is that surfaces that reflect visible light well do the opposite for UV rays; they reflect UV rays poorly.

The only surfaces that I've found based on multiple sources that reflect UV rays to any degree are water/snow (around 80% of UV rays are retained), white sand (around 25% of UV rays are retained), and pavement (again, around 25% of UV rays are retained)

Are those literally the only surfaces that reflect UV rays to any considerable degree? I realize that UV rays are very weak but this is still surprising to me. Also, do UVA rays get reflected better than UVB rays (or vice versa) or do they get reflected at the same rate?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of UV-reflecting materials, or are you asking why a given molecule, along with the crystalline or glassine structure of a material, leads to high reflectivity at one wavelength or another?

Comment: Yes, a list of UV-reflecting materials would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

For example aluminum, even though in the [Thorlabs mirror](http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=264) it has been coated to prolong the life of the mirror, the base is the reflective aluminum.

Check also [Refractiveindex.info](http://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=Al&page=Rakic) for reflectance of materials.